# RegEx match in Google Script = null, but works in JSFiddle/RegExr

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a regex to be able to update calendar event titles that have different training names by turning them into their abbreviations. The regex I created seems to work fine in RegExr and fiddle, but not in google scripts. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bpmsa6yr/1/#&togetherjs=vLRcJvkxx9

Google Script (search is null for "Hunt: Marketing Hub Fundamentals - Location Place")

```
  function abbrevTraining(title){
  console.log(title);
  var regEx = /(?:H[^\s]*)\s([A-Z]).*([A-Z])\w*\s([A-Z])\w*(\s-.*)$/;
  try {var search = title.match(regEx);
       console.log("regex search: "+search);
       var shift = search.shift();
    var newTitle = search.join('');
 
  console.log(title+" new: "+newTitle)
  return newTitle;
      }
  catch(e){return title;}
  
}
```

Comment: Apparently non-capture groups don't work in google scripts, and they aren't planning to fix it. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753681

Comment: I glad you found a solution, however, when I run this (or the sample text in the linked Google tracker issue) I get the expected app script output in the console. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently non-capture groups don't work in google scripts, and they aren't planning to fix it. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753681

I updated to this with success:

```
 var regEx = /^H.*\s([A-Z]).*\s([A-Z])\w*\s([A-Z])\w*(\s-.*)$/;
```

Comment: The issue is no more valid. I get expected output with both the issuetracker example and your question  example also works without error. `search` is not `null`. You must have made a  mistake in your function that calls `abbrevTraining`

Comment: Reproduced the issue with rhino.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is

- reproducible in [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino) engine and
- NOT reproducible in [v8](/questions/tagged/v8) engine.

The issue is already fixed in the newer engine and you should stop using the deprecated engine to dig out old bugs.